# Search word from text file

Tags: c#

I have maybe pretty easy question because I'm new but I did not find any answer for it from google. Idea is search some words from the text file.

Here is the code:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string file = openFileDialog2.FileName;
        try
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
    }
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Search from selected .txt file like: ("a"), ("b"), ("c")
}
```

My English is bad so hopefully you get it and thanks for even trying to help me :)!

Comment: It is _always_ a bad idea to catch and ignore exception.

Comment: have you checked `text` to be else than an empty string. Also try to set a breakpoint within your `catch` section to be sure that `ReadAllText()` isn't throwing an exception

Comment: How do you instantiate your `openFileDialog2` Member, as I suppose it is one.

Comment: You need to store the result of `File.ReadAllText` in a field so that the search method can find it. As it is you're loading it into a local variable that goes out of scope and the test is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple possiblities to check if a text exists.

- With `IndexOf` you can find the statrt index of a string.
- With `Contains` you can check if a string is in another string
- With `StartsWith`/`EndsWith` you can check if a string starts/ends with another string.

---

Just don't forget that `text` value needs to be in the class context to be visible in another method.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string LoadedText { get; } = string.Empty;

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string file = openFileDialog2.FileName;
            try
            {
                LoadedText = File.ReadAllText(file);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                //TODO: error handling
            }
        }
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // use `LoadedText`
        //Search from selected .txt file like: ("a"), ("b"), ("c")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy. You didn't take the time to search.

```
if(text.Contains("THE WORD YOU ARE SEARCHING FOR"))
{
    ///TAKE ACTION
}
```

Another Idea is to `Split` the text files into words **If the text file is not huge** and `iterate through words`. this can help you to find the previous and next words to the searched one.

Comment: error: The name 'text' does not exit in the current context

Comment: 'text' is the variable name you mentioned up there in your code. It should contain the string text inside the file.

Comment: i got it but how i can search many things like ("a", "b", "c")?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole text as a `string` (as you did) and then use either [`String.IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the index of the word (-1 if not found) or use [Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) for that.